# Unable to install USB WiFi device RTL8812AU

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system where I have a RealTek RTL8812AU USB WiFi device. It was working fine until an update and since then I just cannot make it work. Here is some output from various commands:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

# lsusb | grep RTL
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]

# dkms status                                     
nvidia, 510.73.05, 5.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.73.05, 5.15.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.15.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
# dmesg | grep 8812
# 
# lsmod|grep 88
ipmi_msghandler       122880  1 ipmi_devintf
```

I cannot see the device when the machine starts and there is no network. Any help will be appreciated.

Further output from comments

```
# modprobe 8812au
# modinfo 8812au | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko
vermagic:       5.15.0-41-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
# modprobe 88XXau
modprobe: FATAL: Module 88XXau not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic

$ sudo dmesg | grep 8812
[sudo] password for farhat: 
[146965.745499] 8812au: unknown parameter 'rtw_drv_log_level' ignored
[146965.745505] 8812au: unknown parameter 'rtw_led_ctrl' ignored
[146965.745510] 8812au: unknown parameter 'rtw_beamform_cap' ignored
[146965.745512] 8812au: unknown parameter 'rtw_dfs_region_domain' ignored
[146965.745514] 8812au: unknown parameter 'rtw_switch_usb_mode' ignored
[146965.745636] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
[146965.745752] Modules linked in: 8812au(OE+) cfg80211 snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd kvm nvidia_uvm(POE) snd_hda_codec_realtek crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec_generic ghash_clmulni_intel nvidia_drm(POE) aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_modeset(POE) ledtrig_audio crypto_simd snd_seq_midi cryptd snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg nvidia(POE) input_leds snd_intel_sdw_acpi rapl snd_rawmidi snd_hda_codec gspca_zc3xx snd_hda_core drm_kms_helper snd_seq ucsi_ccg snd_hwdep typec_ucsi gspca_main cec videobuf2_vmalloc wmi_bmof typec snd_pcm rc_core videobuf2_memops fb_sys_fops snd_seq_device syscopyarea sysfillrect videobuf2_v4l2 sysimgblt snd_timer videobuf2_common mxm_wmi videodev snd mc soundcore k10temp ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid nvme igb crc32_pclmul i2c_algo_bit ahci xhci_pci gpio_amdpt nvme_core i2c_nvidia_gpu
[146965.745841]  ? _rtw_malloc+0x2d/0x2f [8812au]
[146965.745873]  ? _rtw_memcpy+0x10/0x12 [8812au]
[146965.745902]  ? rtw_5g_rates_init+0x1a/0x1c [8812au]
[146965.745933]  rtw_wdev_alloc+0xfc/0x2a2 [8812au]
[146965.745964]  rtw_usb_if1_init+0x10b/0x229 [8812au]
[146965.745993]  rtw_drv_init+0x364/0x3fb [8812au]
[146965.746051]  rtw_drv_entry+0x65/0x1000 [8812au]
[146966.040500] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
[219920.658812] pcieport 0000:00:01.1:   device [1022:1453] error status/mask=00001000/00006000
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of these terminal commands:  `lsmod | grep 88` and finally: `sudo dmesg | grep 8812` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks! added the output. it is empty.

Comment: added the output for lsmod as well.

Comment: It's clear that the module didn't load as expected. Let's find out why. `sudo modprobe 8812au` Please edit to include any warnings, errors, etc.

Comment: Also try: `sudo modprobe 88XXau` and post any errors or warnings.

Comment: @chili555 it looks like the rtl8812au-dkms from the Ubuntu repos is installed and I think the dkms part has been broken since 2016

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @Jeremy31 It builds and modprobes on my 22.04 system. Let's see what OP discovers.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `modinfo 8812au | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'`

Comment: @chili555 the issue usually happens after the first kernel update after installing rtl8812au-dkms but if the kernel update was done without a reboot before installing rtl8812au-dkms it could happen right away

Comment: Thanks for helping... `modprobe` did not have any output.

Comment: Now are there clues in the message log? `sudo dmesg | grep 8812`

Comment: There seems to be a bunch of info. Does this help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that we try a different driver alltogether. First, remove the old, defective driver:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
```

Next, let's install a newer driver:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git
cd 8821au-20210708
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks, works now! Even picked up my earlier settings for wifi networks.