# After software update of kernel on ubuntu 22.04 TP-Link ac600 archer wifi adaper stopped working

Tags: drivers, kernel

My kernel version now is 5.19.0-32-generic on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Adapter was working in 2g and 5g modes perfectly before software update.

I tried some methods as shown here for 20.04 and earlier versions. But no success. I am stuck up.

Can anyone help with tried method?

Comment: Did you install any drivers for it? They probably didn't build for the new kernel.

Comment: When the driver for new kernel version 5.19 is released, kindly notify.

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb; dkms status` to the question by [edit]

Answer (score 2):

To solve my problem i had this commands:

1. Remove the old and problematic driver:

`sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms`

2. Install the new one:

`git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git`

`cd 8821au-20210708`

`sudo ./install-driver.sh`

I have used with sucess the proposed solution defined at [Unable to install USB WiFi device RTL8812AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419477/unable-to-install-usb-wifi-device-rtl8812au)

Comment: Thank you so much, this enabled me to perfectly access the internet on 22.04. Much easier than on 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it to work with kernel 5.19.0-32-generic either.

I was able to solve it by changing grub to the previous kernel 5.15.0-60-generic.

Step by step:
Install Grub Customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Open Grub Customizer
Click the General Settings and select "predefined" button, then the option of 5.15.0-60-generic kernel. It is a temporary solution until someone fixes the driver.

Now you can restart your computer.

Comment: Followed this procedure and it started working fine. Thanks for this temporary solution.

Comment: It is not a good idea to freeze kernel. It is not hard to fix it with 5.19.

Comment: This also worked for me. Downgraded the kernel, wifi working again. Thanks for the tips. 

Scott

Comment: @Pilot6 You are right; it is a temporary solution until someone fixes the driver. I'll edit my answer.